# How does VC++ mangle local static variable names?

Tags: c++, scope

Here's some code I have:

```
MyClass* MyClass::getInstance()
{
   static MyClass instance;
   return &instance;
}
```

I want to look into this singleton's current values. But I'm currently paused three hours into execution, and the reason I'm paused is that I'm out of memory. So I can't put a breakpoint in this method there to see what the value is.

My question then is how to refer to this `instance` variable from a global scope. I've tried referring to it as `MyClass::getInstance::instance` but that doesn't work. I'm guessing `getInstance` has to be decorated somehow. Anyone know how?

This is in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Why just don't do it the class member? Local static variables are not the best thing to debug

Comment: class MyClass {
  MyClass *instance;
  MyClass *getInstance() {
   return instance;
  }
}

Comment: Yeah... I know if I could change the code then this would be trivial. But as I said this is mid-run so I'm looking for a solution that leaves the code as-is.

Comment: Can't you just get the address of it at startup? Then simply check that address when it runs out of memory

Comment: Yes, yes I could. But if there's a way to do it now then I don't have to wait three hours! I also thought it would be an interesting exercise to determine how the variable could be referenced from a global context.

Comment: 1 suggestion that may not work. Use windbg or userdump to dump your app, then you can inspect it in windbg after you've stopped it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the function-scoped static `instance` variable doesn't show up in a `.map` file generated by `cl.exe /Fm`, and it doesn't show up when I use `x programname!*MyClass*` in WinDbg, so the mangled name doesn't seem to contain `MyClass` at all.

**Option 1: Disassemble `MyClass::getInstance`**

This approach seems easier:

```
0:000> uf programname!MyClass::getInstance
programname!MyClass::getInstance [programname.cpp @ 14]:
   14 00401050 55              push    ebp
   14 00401051 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
   15 00401053 a160b34200      mov     eax,dword ptr [programname!$S1 (0042b360)]
   15 00401058 83e001          and     eax,1
   15 0040105b 7526            jne     funcstat!MyClass::getInstance+0x33 (00401083)

programname!MyClass::getInstance+0xd [programname.cpp @ 15]:
   15 0040105d 8b0d60b34200    mov     ecx,dword ptr [programname!$S1 (0042b360)]
   15 00401063 83c901          or      ecx,1
   15 00401066 890d60b34200    mov     dword ptr [programname!$S1 (0042b360)],ecx
   15 0040106c b9b0be4200      mov     ecx,offset programname!instance (0042beb0)
   15 00401071 e88fffffff      call    programname!ILT+0(??0MyClassQAEXZ) (00401005)
   15 00401076 68e03e4200      push    offset programname!`MyClass::getInstance'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'instance'' (00423ee0)
   15 0040107b e8f3010000      call    programname!atexit (00401273)
   15 00401080 83c404          add     esp,4

programname!MyClass::getInstance+0x33 [programname.cpp @ 16]:
   16 00401083 b8b0be4200      mov     eax,offset programname!instance (0042beb0)
   17 00401088 5d              pop     ebp
   17 00401089 c3              ret
```

From this we can tell that the compiler called the object `$S1`. Of course, this name will depend on how many function-scoped static variables your program has.

**Option 2: Search memory for the object**

To expand on @gbjbaanb's suggestion, if `MyClass` has virtual functions, you might be able to find its location the hard way:

- Make a full memory dump of the process.
- Load the full memory dump into WinDbg.
- Use the `x` command to find the address of MyClass's vtable:

```
    0:000> x programname!MyClass::`vftable'
    00425c64 programname!MyClass::`vftable' =
```

- Use the `s` command to search the process's virtual address space (in this example, 0-2GB) for pointers to MyClass's vtable:

```
    0:000> s -d 0 L?7fffffff 00425c64
    004010dc  00425c64 c35de58b cccccccc cccccccc  d\B...].........
    0040113c  00425c64 8bfc458b ccc35de5 cccccccc  d\B..E...]......
    0042b360  00425c64 00000000 00000000 00000000  d\B.............
```

- Use the `dt` command to find the class's vtable offset, and subtract that from the addresses returned from the search. These are possible addresses for the object.

```
    0:000> dt programname!MyClass
       +0x000 __VFN_table      : Ptr32 
       +0x008 x                : Int4B
       +0x010 y                : Float
```

- Use `dt programname!MyClass 0042b360` to examine the object's member variables, testing the hypothesis that the object is located at 0042b360 (or some other address). You will probably get some false positives, as I did above, but by inspecting the member variables you may be able to figure out which one is your singleton.

This is a general technique for finding C++ objects, and is kind of overkill when you could just disassemble `MyClass::getInstance`.

Comment: As it was nowhere mentioned I might recommend the `undname` tool, which is included in VS, which can be used to decipher the mangled symbols

Comment: @EFraim: I agree, `undname` is very useful for dealing with decorated symbols. However, I don't think it would have helped with finding function-scoped static variables, because MSVC doesn't seem to decorate those so much as completely rename them (to `$S1`, `$S2`, etc.).

Comment: If you use `dumpbin /symbols` on the `.obj` file, you'll likely find both `$S1` and `instance` as static variables, with really ugly names like `?instance@?1??getInstance@MyClass@@SAPAV2@XZ@4V2@A` and `?$S1@?1??getInstance@MyClass@@SAPAV2@XZ@4IA`.  I'm not really sure what the reason for having both of them is, but it appears that an `$Sx` variable is generated if a local static variable is initialised from a function parameter.  [Note that I tested with Studio 2010, which may have changed conventions since 2008.]

Comment: From what I can tell, it emits an additional `$Sx` variable if the local static variable is initialised dynamically, but not if it's initialised statically.  Made a quick test source file, compiled with `cl /c`, obtained mangled names with `dumpbin /symbols`, and uploaded to ideone for you: http://ideone.com/2vjjhu

Comment: @bk1e I found the variable name as abcexe!\`ns1::c1::fn1::\`2'::$TSS0  how do i view this object ?  `? <full_name>` gives me generic error - could not resolve error at <full_name>

Answer (score 1):

In gdb, you can put a watchpoint on the mangled name of the variable.

For example, with this function:

```
int f() {
    static int xyz = 0;
    ++xyz;

    return xyz;
}
```

I can watch _ZZ1fvE3xyz (as mangled by gcc 3.2.3 or gcc 4.0.1).

Comment: Awesome... That's the sort of thing I was looking for, only for the MS compiler. Good to know that it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

That code just looks dangerous... :-)

But anyway, your mangled name is going to depend on your [Calling Convention](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/calling_conventions_demystified.aspx)  So before you find your mangle name you need to know what your build environment is using as the calling convention. MSDN has a lot more information on calling convention.

Besides this, one way to find out all this information about your class is to inspect your VTable, which is found in the first 4 bytes of your object.  A nifty trick that reversers use is a hidden VC++ Flag [reportSingleClassLayout](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/05/17/diagnosing-hidden-odr-violations-in-visual-c-and-fixing-lnk2022.aspx) that prints the class structure in an ASCII art manner.