# What can cause Visual Studio to see a struct appear as a float in the "Watch" window?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have a function that compares 2 structs for equality. The function has been returning strange results, so I watched it in visual studio, only to discover that it has changed the parameters to floats!

The function is declared like this:

```
int compareStructs(struct command s1, struct command s2) /*Returns true if they are equal*/
{
    if (s1.command == s2.command && s1.parameter == s2.parameter)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and is then called from code like this:

```
    if (!compareStructs(newCommand, payload))
    {
        printf("new command from safe\n");
        payload = newCommand;
    }
```

When I watch the variables s1 and s2, they appear as "floats" in the Watch window, as seen here:
[image: Debug window]

It looks like visual studio is putting a `$` before the `s1` so maybe that means something. What could cause a struct to appear as a float in the debug window?

Comment: The float is `Ss1`, not `s1`. Type `s1`instead of `Ss1`.

Comment: On a side note, it would be more efficient so pass pointers to `compareStructs` instead of structs. If `struct command` is large, passing by value is extreamly inefficient.

Comment: Well, you are definitely not looking at the struct.  The $ prefix is special, it is used for pseudo-variables (like $err) and [variables generated by the compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292962/17034).  Exactly where it came from and why the watch expression selected $s1 instead of s1 is impossible to guess from the question.  Report bugs at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @Michael Walz I think it is actually a `$` sign. It appears when I highlight s1, right click, and press "Add Watch"